# Java Ubuntu Linux Swing Blank Window

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu, joptionpane

I'm writing a Java desktop application, running Ubuntu 10.10. Everything works fine except that about 1 in 10 times, when I call JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message), the dialog window appears but it is empty -- just the standard gray background. Strangely, a few times when this has happened I have been able to click where the OK button ***should*** have been and it registered the click fine. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Do you have code you can show us?

Comment: I don't mind sharing any code, but it's several hundred lines of code that I don't think anyone would want to read through. I was more curious if this was a problem with Java Ubuntu/Linux, as I've had this problem in multiple programs on Ubuntu but never on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which JVM are you using? Make sure it's not [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) (as it often is by default Ubuntu/Debian).  It's swing implementation is a little odd and will often elicit strange behavior like that.

Comment: I'm actually not sure. gcj is the default on my system (how do I change this?) but in an attempt to fix this, I wrote a shell script that sets Eclipse's jvm to the sun-java-6-sun-1.6.0.22 jvm, so I assume that when I build a program in Eclipse it would use this jvm, right?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can use `sudo update-java-alternatives -s <name>` to set the jvm. Use `sudo update-java-alternatives -l` to see a list of jvms available.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you displaying the dialog from the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)? Strange bugs with symptons like this might occur from time to time if Swings *single thread rule* is violated.

Answer (score 0):

I subscribe to Uhlen's post. The most probable cause is that you might not use Event Dispatch Thread for Swing code. Example:

```
try {
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Message");
        }
    });
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {

} catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {

}
```